# Как получить позицию курсора в RichEditor (WYSIWYG текстовый редактор для Android)

Tags: javascript, android, wysiwyg, курсор

Как получать позицию курсора в тексте при использовании [RichEditor](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android/blob/master/richeditor/src/main/java/jp/wasabeef/richeditor/RichEditor.java#L39) для Android?

Объявил в активити:

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.article_body)
    RichEditor body;

    @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_article);

            ButterKnife.bind(this);
    }

    private class RichOnTextChangeListener implements RichEditor.OnTextChangeListener {

        private RichOnTextChangeListener() {
            
        }

        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        @Override
        public void onTextChange(String text) {

       
        }
    }
}
```

Так выглядит в xml view редактора:

```
<jp.wasabeef.richeditor.RichEditor
 android:id="@+id/article_body"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:padding="16dp"
 android:scrollHorizontally="true" />
```

Все примеры которые нахожу - используют `id` элемента в котором находится текст:

> var el=document.getElementById(<тут нужно ввести 'id'>);
>
> el.selectionStart;

Но как получить(узнать) `id` в данном редакторе не знаю.

Пытался с помощью скриптов получить `id` элемента который находится в фокусе - пишет: *undefined*.

Если так:

```
body.loadUrl("javascript: print (var el = document.getAttribute('id'));");
```

Получаю:

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var", source: file:///android_asset/editor.html (1)
```

===============================================================

**UPD:**

```
body.loadUrl("javascript:(function getSelectionText() {" +
            "   var poz = getSelection(); " +
            "   print( poz.anchorOffset ); " +
            " })();");
```

В таком случае получаю только позицию курсора относительно начала строки, а не начала текста.

Comment: `editor` его id - подсмотреть `html` можно в папке: [`assets`](https://github.com/wasabeef/richeditor-android/tree/master/richeditor/src/main/assets), там же есть скрипт, обеспечивающий все операции с редактором - загляните, может найдёте, что-то полезное, я в JS не очень.

Comment: Не получается так. Пишет в консоли: Uncaught ReferenceError: body is not defined", source: file:///android_asset/editor.html (1)

Comment: И когда я получаю html, то там просто текст и теги по типу <b>...</b> и т.д. . Но нет ни одного "id". Когда выкладываю текст на сайт - там тоже нет "id". Потому и застопорился.

Comment: Ну или может я не так его получать пытаюсь, в JS то не силен.

Comment: Может эта библиотека Вам не подходит? Это скорее текстовый редактор с дополнительными плюшками, но никак не полноценный редактор `html` для работы над сайтом. Насчёт `id` - Вы наверное своими скриптами прибили единственный `div` с `id`, а то и всю оригинальную страничку перезаписали. Больше этот редактор никаких `id` не добавляет.

Comment: Та нет, скриптов то левых не добавлял до этого момента, и пользовался методами которые разработчик приводит  в своей библиотеке. Та ну с ним с этим `id` - 'это рассматривал как вариант. Но должен же быть способ получать не только по `id`.

Comment: getSelection() - срабатывает, но(!) он выдает только количество символов с начала той строки в которую поставлен, а не с начала всего текста - непонятно. Такое чувство будто он отсчитывает от ближайшего <br> стоящего слева от курсора.

Comment: Тут вот в чём проблема - каждый кусок текста он добавляет как отдельный элемент, а JS соответственно отдаёт позицию внутри одного элемента. Что бы получить позицию во всём тексте, видимо нужно пересчитать его во всех предыдущих элементах. Посмотрите на [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=get+caret+position+in+contenteditable+div) - там есть какие-то решения

Comment: @woesss оформите пожалуйста свой комментарий как ответ